# Move DatagridRow to last row after clicking button

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview and i want to insert a number into one of the columns and press save. upon that it should move that row to last row. but my code does not work?

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        try
        {
            cabinfo2BindingSource.EndEdit();
            cabinfo2TableAdapter.Update(this.dispatchDataSet.cabinfo2);
            MessageBox.Show("Bidding information Updated Successfully ", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[3], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    }
```

Comment: I want the saved row to be last but its in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

You move to last row with this code:

```cs
int nRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[0];
```

Just put this code end of the btnSave_Click method.

Comment: that does not move the record below it only moves the bluebox. see i have a few records like name and phonenumber. if first row is ahmed 123 once i edit it to ahmed 124 it should go all the way down as in last row of all the records. sorry for english